# repeat elements of string array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a String array with 4 elements. I want to extend this String array with the same elements repeated 3 or n times.

For Example, for the array

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
```

I want to have something like

```
String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d" };
```

I tried to something as follows:

```
String[] columnHeaderNamesArray = {"A","b","c","d"};
String[] extendedColumnHeaderNamesArray = new String[columnHeaderNamesArray.length * 3];
            Arrays.fill(extendedColumnHeaderNamesArray, columnHeaderNamesArray);
```

But I got an `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeating the elements of an array](/q/32305652)

Comment: Did you check javadoc of fill?

Comment: `Arrays.fill()` doesn't treat you array as actually array, it's considered as object. So, you're trying to fill array of string with object of array, it's not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-) to create several copies of the same array, and then flat map them to a single array:

```
String[] multiplied =
    Collections.nCopies(4, array)
               .stream()
               .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
               .toArray(String[]::new);
```